# html5 video - plays on desktop, iPhone 6s, won't play on 5s?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video

Any idea why an HTML5 video would play on an iPhone 6s Plus but not an iPhone 5s? I'm getting a full page load on the 5s, including video poster and play button, but the button and video are unresponsive.

Here's the page: http://www.2labsnc.com/index.html
(for anyone using a desktop, the video is behind the large main photo).

Here's the code (a modified version of the Porto Theme by Okler):

```
<div role="main" class="main">
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider" id="revolutionSlider" data-plugin-revolution-slider data-plugin-options='{"startheight": 500}'>
            <ul>
                <li data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1000" data-fstransition="fade" data-fsmasterspeed="1000" data-fsslotamount="7">
                    <img src="img/slides/BG-Slide.png" alt="dark" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" alt="Click to Play">
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-fade fadeout fullscreenvideo"
                    data-x="0"
                    data-y="0"
                    data-speed="1000"
                    data-start="100"
                    data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                    data-endspeed="1500"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"
                    data-autoplay="false"
                    data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="false"
                    data-nextslideatend="true"
                    data-volume="2"
                    data-forceCover="1"
                    data-aspectratio="16:9"
                    data-forcerewind="on">
                        <video preload="none" controls="true" width="100%" height="100%" poster="img/slides/BG-Slide.png"  loop video> 
                            <source src="video/BG_intro_sound.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="video/BG_intro_sound.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
....
```

Thanks for any help that you might be able to provide!

Answer (score 1):

You can check in canuse http://caniuse.com/#feat=video  if the browser you are using (or which version) support html5 video tag.

Comment: Looks like I'm all clear there - using mobile Chrome in both cases. I wasn't aware of that site though, thanks for the link!

Comment: Yeah - current release in both cases (46).

Comment: Check also for level of operating system. Because in some operating system the support for html5 video is partial... refer to chrome doc for this

Comment: Both are running ios 9.1.

Same thing is happening with Safari mobile. The video works on the 6S, but not the 5S.